# JavaScript Moment.js Parsing Timezone Incorrectly

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone, momentjs

I have the following JavaScript code using Moment.js.

```js
const time = "Thu Nov 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400";
const momentTime = moment(time, "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss GMT-ZZ");
console.log(momentTime.toString()); // Thu Nov 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Problem is I expect the following values to equal each other (they are not currently):

- `time` (`Thu Nov 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400`)
- `momentTime.toString()` (`Thu Nov 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600`)

I'm expecting `momentTime.toString()` to equal `Wed Oct 31 2018 22:00:00 GMT-0600` (if I did my math correctly).

It looks like it's just parsing that timezone or GMT offset incorrectly for some reason.

According to the [Moment.js parsing documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) I should be able to use `ZZ` to parse it into the correct time zone.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your problem is the timezone token when parsing. Instead of "GMT-ZZ" use "ZZ".

Comment: @RobG That worked! Feel free to leave an answer and I'll upvote and accept. The reason I thought I needed `GMT-ZZ` is because in the documentation it says `Offset from UTC as +-HH:mm, +-HHmm, or Z` as the example. Really tripped me up since I thought it was only going to parse the `-0400` not the `GMT-0400`. Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah, the documentation means that ZZ represents the entire timezone string, not just the HH:mm part. :-) I think it sees "GMT-ZZ" as an invalid token and ignores it.

Comment: Moment uses square brackets to escape tokens, so if you want to be explicit you can use `[GMT]ZZ`.  Not necessary for parsing unless you turn on strict mode, but may be desired for formatting output either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments changing the code to the following worked:

```js
const time = "Thu Nov 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400";
const momentTime = moment(time, "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ");
console.log(momentTime.toString()); // Wed Oct 31 2018 22:00:00 GMT-0600
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

So basically changing `GMT-ZZ` to `ZZ` in the format string worked.